# One Multisite SSL on Two virtual hosts (Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ssl, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, multisite

I have one SSL certificate from GoDaddy (Standard UCC SSL Certificate for up to 5 sub/domains) and two virtual hosts configuration on Apache2.

I can install SSL certificate one every of them separately and they works fine until I add second one.

When the second HTTPS config is added (...), then I am getting kind of weird redirects from one.abc.com to two.abc or vice versa.

I am using the same certificate files for both configs, because it the same Multisite SSL certificate.

F.ex.:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/abc.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/abc.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/abc_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName subd2.abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test2
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/abc.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/abc.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/abc_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This:

> Now - I understand that because SSL wraps around the HTTP request,
>   there's no way to know which host is being requested until a public
>   key has been sent to the client first. This essentially breaks the
>   possibility of SSL virtual hosts using a standard SSL certificate.

from
https://serverfault.com/questions/113076/apache-ssl-virtualhosts-on-a-single-ip-using-ucc-san-certificate
Lead me to idea that problem is simple that in case of abc.com server just do not know which HTTPS server (www.abc.com or subd2.abc.com) config to take and simply take the first one. Tests that approved.

From that comes second question / conclusion - do I have configuration for domain abc.com. And it has not, I just have it defined as ServerAlias in www.abc.com config.

When I removed from ServerAlias and created configuration with for abc.com and with redirect, than all stays in their places.